# kali linux stopped booting to gui after installing 3.5inch touchscreen drivers, startx and all other gui packages are not working

Tags: kali-linux, drivers, raspberry-pi, gui

First time posting sorry if this isn't formatted properly.

After installing [this](https://github.com/lcdwiki/LCD-show-kali) driver on kali for my 3.5inch raspberry pi 4 touchscreen, kali has automatically been booting to text mode (no errors in booting) and I can't get it to boot back to gui mode or even enter gui mode. all normal GUI repair/reinstall steps are not working.

(note kali always booted to gui before installing the driver, and I have installed the driver on PiOS without any issues.)

When attempting startx I get this:

```
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux kali-raspberry-pi 5.15.44-Re4son-v7l+ #1 SMP Debian kali-pi (2022-07-03) armv7l
Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=480 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=320 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=E4:5F:01:8B:7C:07 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3eb00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3ff00000  console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=1a995292-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait net.ifnames=0
xorg-server 2:21.1.4-1 (https://www.debian.org/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Oct  4 10:02:03 2022
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

I've done the obvious of updating and reinstalling lightdm which didn't work, I also installed gdm3 and tried to open the gui using that, to no avail.

I also completely reinstalled the OS a few times along with attempting to use the provided kali OS provided by the 3.5inch screen devs with the drivers preinstalled. It didn't even boot so I couldn't ssh into it.

I am somewhat new to linux and have only been using it for a month or two but I've looked through all relevant questions and nothing seems to work for it.

Again, sorry if this is a bit messy I'm still learning the ropes of stack.

edit 1 : the script I ran to install the driver was this

```
sudo rm -rf LCD-show-kali
git clone https://github.com/lcdwiki/LCD-show-kali.git
chmod -R 755 LCD-show-kali
cd LCD-show-kali/
sudo ./MPI3508-show
sudo reboot
```

(I'm using kali for personal projects learning about pen testing and network security btw. I've already used Ubuntu for about 2 months, which is why I'm pretty fresh to kali)

Comment: The issue is because Xorg can't find a screen driver: `Fatal server error:` / `(EE) no screens found(EE)`. The reason for that is unclear at this point. Which driver configuration script did you run? If it's not too long please add it (name and contents) to your question so we can see what it did

Comment: By the way, if you're new to Linux then Kali is a poor choice of distribution. It's a specialist pen-tester distribution not a general purpose one. I'd recommend a "friendlier" distribution such as Mint or Ubuntu

Comment: ... and on Mint or Ubuntu you can run everything you run in Kali, just with less problems.

Comment: edited answer to for details on above, I'm assuming you meant the script I ran to clone the git repo onto kali, not 100% sure if that's what you meant though.